# How to interpolate several values contained in a variable into a json string

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a `parsed` variable obtained after parsing some text:

```
parsed=$(echo "PA-232 message1 GX-1234 message2 PER-10 message3" | grep -Eo '[A-Z]+-[0-9]+')
```

`parsed` contains a bunch of ids:

```
echo $parsed
PA-232
GX-1234
PER-10
```

The next thing I have to do in my script is generate a json text and invoke an API with it:

The json text should be

```
"{\"tasks\": [{\"taskId\": \"PA-232\"}, {\"taskId\": \"GX-1234\"}, {\"taskId\": \"PER-10\"}], \"projectId\": \"$CI_PROJECT_ID\" }"
```

Notice `CI_PROJECT_ID` is an envvar that I also have to send, thats why I needed to use double quotes and escape them.

And it would be called with curl:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -k -u $CLIENT_ID:$CLIENT_SECRET 'https://somewhere.com/api/tasks' -d "{\"tasks\": [{\"taskId\": \"PA-232\"}, {\"taskId\": \"GX-1234\"}, {\"taskId\": \"PER-10\"}], \"projectId\": \"$CI_PROJECT_ID\"}"
```

The question is how can I generate a json string like the one shown above from the `parsed` variable and the additional envvar?

Comment: Please read the descriptions of the tags you applied. Approximately half of them are misplaced.

Comment: Have you read any of our existing Q&A about generating JSON from bash? If you show how you tried to apply existing answers, that would get you a lot closer to a complete solution. (If you use jq successfully and have regular output, f/e, telling jq to convert that to double-escaped output is trivial).

Comment: ...right now, this is combining a lot of separate, already-answered questions -- how to split a string into multiple variables, how to pass variables into jq, how to tell jq to perform double-escaping, etc. It's not reasonable to ask people to write a custom answer just for you combining N different answers that are already complete -- make an attempt, and if you get stuck somewhere that _isn't_ in our knowledgebase, come in with a narrow, focused question about that.

Comment: ...that said, your curl example **isn't** doing double escaping, because the outer quotes are syntactic (for the shell's consumption), and only the inner ones are literal (part of the data passed to curl). So the _actual data_ doesn't have any backslashes in it at all.

Comment: ...an alternate way to describe that: `"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"` is _the exact same string_ as `'{"foo": "bar"}'`; you only need the backslashes when you're putting double quotes _inside of other double quotes_, not when you put them in single quotes. And data coming from a variable expanded in double quotes is always completely literal -- none of the data in the variable is ever interpreted as shell syntax at all, unless you're doing awful things like using `eval`.

Comment: BTW, bash and sh are two different shells; please tag only for the one you're actually using. (If you're starting bash _under the name_ `sh`, it turns off a number of features for the sake of compatibility; unless you have a good reason to do that, it's not advised -- and on many common distros such as Debian and Ubuntu, `sh` is not bash at all).

Comment: I can't use jq since this bash script is running in Gitlab CICD and the base images doesn't have it available: `$ jq -> /bin/bash: line 148: jq: command not found`

Comment: Do the base images provide Python? Python has perfectly good JSON parsers, and we have existing Q&A describing how to use that from bash as well.

Comment: (that said, I thought you could use any Docker container you chose in gitlab; is that wrong? -- indeed, reviewing https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html, it seems to be rather affirmatively _not_ wrong)

Comment: You're right, this client is using `image: maven:3.8.6-jdk-11` but I guess I could generate a custom image including jq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing it with `jq`?

```bash
CI_PROJECT_ID='I want this " to be escaped automatically'

echo 'PA-232 message1 GX-1234 message2 PER-10 message3' |

jq -R --arg ciProjectId "$CI_PROJECT_ID" '
    {
        tasks: [
            capture( "(?<taskId>[[:upper:]]+-[[:digit:]]+)"; "g" )
        ],
        projectId: $ciProjectId
    }
'
```

```json
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskiD": "PA-232"
    },
    {
      "taskiD": "GX-1234"
    },
    {
      "taskiD": "PER-10"
    }
  ],
  "projectId": "I want this \" to be escaped automatically"
}
```

<sup>**note:** you can use `jq -c ...` for outputting a *compact* JSON</sup>

---

And here's a solution without `jq` that **doesn't escape the characters in the strings so it might generate invalid JSON**:

```
CI_PROJECT_ID='no escaping needed'

tasks_jsonArr=$(
    echo "PA-232 message1 GX-1234 message2 PER-10 message3" |
    grep -Eo '[A-Z]+-[0-9]+' |
    sed 's/.*/{ "taskiD": "&" }/' |
    paste -sd ',' |
    sed 's/.*/[ & ]/'
)

curl -k 'https://somewhere.com/api/tasks' \
     -X POST \
     -H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
     -u "$CLIENT_ID:$CLIENT_SECRET" \
     -d "{\"tasks\": $tasks_jsonArr, \"projectId\": \"$CI_PROJECT_ID\"}"
```

**N.B.** For JSON-escaping strings with standard tools, take a look at [function json_stringify in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73777329/3387716)

Comment: It might be worth emphasizing that "that doesn't JSON-escape anything" means "that can submit invalid non-JSON content the server will reject".